# Is it possible to manually select order in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i have table:

```
table1
------------
id  |  name
------------
1   |  John
2   |  Steeve
3   |  Walter
4   |  Daniel
5   |  Jeremy
6   |  Carmelo
...
```

What i need is to select from table in order i manually enter e.g. id 5,3,6,1,4,2

```
SELECT * FROM talbe1 ORDER BY (5,3,6,1,4,2)
```

Is it possible somehow?
Thanks!

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to have another table which maps the key to sorting order and then join that table. Or, to avoid the join, add a third column which will be used for sorting only.

Comment: what is the need/logic behind this sequence??

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` [`FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT * FROM talbe1 ORDER BY FIELD(id, 5,3,6,1,4,2)
```

Comment: it is stated in given link that `FIELD` Returns the index (position) of `str `in the `str1, str2, str3, ...` list. Returns **0** if str is not found. will you elaborate how this Query use this function??

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try this:

```
SELECT * FROM talbe1 ORDER BY FIELD(id,'5','3','6','1','4','2')
```